flutter_hooks - how to access TextEditingController outside the build()-method?
Flutter hooks needs to be created within the build method of a widget by design.
Let's assume I have a hook for using a TextEditingController, how can I access the TextEditingController outside the build method to access the text for e.g. validation or clearing the text on specific conditions?
class SearchTermInputOneInt extends HookConsumerWidget
    implements SearchTermInput {
  @override
  final List<String> captionList;

  const SearchTermInputOneInt({super.key, required this.captionList});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final textEditingController = useTextEditingController();
    return TextFormField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: captionList.isNotEmpty ? captionList[0] : "",
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: textEditingController.clear,
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        ),
      ),
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(3)
      ],
      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
        var doSearch = ref.read(doSearchFunctionProvider);
        doSearch!(context, ref);
      },
    );
  } 

How can I access the textEditingController instance outside the build method in other functions within my SearchTermInputOneInt class?

Stop using hooks here.  Use a stateful widget, and then put the TEC in your state.

ok, did it that way. thanks
